# MPMusicPlayerController take 7 sec to start playing in Xamarin.IOS ( IOS v11.3)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, delay, upgrade, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am developing Xamarin.IOS Application. In my application, I used User music for alarm purpose in my application. I use MPMusicPlayerController.ApplicationMusicPlayer to Play alarm.

When I tried to play alarm for the first time when the application open, it takes around 7 sec to start playing the alarm. From the second time, if I play the alarm play instantly. Bellow is my code to play alarm.

```
var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.ApplicationMusicPlayer;
musicPlayer.SetQueue(MPMediaQuery.SongsQuery);
musicPlayer.Play();
```

This problem only occurs in IOS v11.3. Until IOS v11.2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `PrepareToPlay()` .

Calling this method preloads buffers and acquires the audio hardware needed for playback, which minimizes the lag between calling the `play()` method and the start of sound output.

Details refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386886-preparetoplay).